# How to feed the output of one R Shiny input to another

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to pass one Shiny input's value to another.  My goal is to have a slider's value default to the value that corresponds to a selection from a dropdown above it.  That is, I'm hoping that there's a way to pass the choice from `selectInput()` (essentially `input$Character`) to the value argument in `sliderInput()`.  I want to try something like the below code, but it is an utter failure.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId="Character", label="Choose Your Character",
                             choices=starwars$name),
    sel = starwars %>% filter(name==input$name) %>% select(height),
    sliderInput(inputId="height", label="Choose character height ", min=0, 
                max=max(starwars$height), value=sel)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput('text')
    )
)

server <- fuction(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    print(input$height)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this in the UI code directly. You'll need to do it in the server using a function like [updateSliderInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/updateSliderInput.html) See the examples on the documentation page.

Comment: Damn, that's what I was afraid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be afraid of using server-side processing, it's pretty straightforward!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        selectInput("character",
            "Choose your character",
            choices = starwars$name
        ),
        uiOutput("height_ui"),
        verbatimTextOutput('text')
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$height_ui <- renderUI({

        selected_character_height <- starwars %>%
            filter(name == input$character) %>%
            pull(height)

        sliderInput("height",
            "Choose character height ",
            min = 0L, 
            max = max(starwars$height, na.rm = TRUE),
            value = selected_character_height
        )
    })
    
    output$text <- renderPrint({
        print(input$height)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```